# git reset --hard to commit does not work - Tip is HEAD is behind

Tags: git, github, version-control

I want to reset my local branch to the commit `as288sa`. 
The commit is stored on the remote repository and my local repository. 
I want to reset using the `--hard` flag.

```
git reset --hard as288sa
```

> Checking out files
>   HEAD is now at as288sa

I then want to `add` and `commit` the `reset` and `push` that commit to the remote repository.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "reseted hard"
```

> On branch myBranch
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

```
git push origin myBranch
```

> rejected
>   error: failed to push some refs to git@...
>   Updates were rejected because the tip of you current branch is behind
>   its counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. git pull) before pushing changes

So I did a `git pull`, then `git add -A` and a `git commit` as well as a `git push` and tried then the `git reset --hard as288sa`.
I get the same error message again.

What is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't "add and commit a reset"; add and commit is how you apply working tree changes to create a new commit, whereas reset just moves a ref to point to an existing commit.  I would expect the `add` and `commit` commands to complain about nothing to add / empty commit, unless you had unrelated changes in your working tree.

Well, anyway, then you try to push but as you see git doesn't like it because you're trying to push a ref to an ancestor and git doesn't think that's a good idea.  It tells you to do a pull, but when you do that undoes your reset by moving your local ref for myBranch right back to where the origin had put it before.

So that's what happened... but before I tell you how you can fix it, I should mention that what you're doing will cause anyone else pulling myBranch to have a problem, and if there are very many users this probably isn't what you want to do.

**To do what you asked**, after the reset but without doing a pull (and don't even worry about add or commit) you can do a push with the -f flag.  You may or may not have permission to do this, but even if you do, seriously, it is likely not what you want to do.

**Instead what I suspect you really should do** is revert the commit - i.e. create a new commit that reverses the changes from the previous commits returning the tree to the same state as an earlier commit but in a way that preserves the published history.  Look at the docs for `git revert`

Comment: Why dont I want to `reset` the `commit` with the `--hard` flag? I know that this delets all the `commits` that are ahead of the `commit` I reset it to. However, if I dont care losing them? How would that be problematic for others?

Comment: At any given time, when pulling from a remote git wants to assume that the local reference for a branch is equal to, or reachable from (i.e. an ancestor of), the remote reference for the same branch.  If you move the remote ref for a branch backwards, and then maybe start moving it down a divergent path, then every other user of that repo will find that assumption broken.  They can recover, but if they've made other changes on the branch they'll have to rebase those changes.  If the repo is shared it's generally poor form to remove a published commit or move a published head "backwards"